# Path to file on a Mac: FileNotFoundException

Tags: java

I'm working on a mac and I'm trying to specify the path to a file on my desktop.

I just did it like this: `File file = new File("/users/desktop/sample.json");`

When I tried running it I got a FileNotFoundException.

How do I correctly specify the path?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since you're looking for your desktop folder in particular, and not the root folder of a user with the name "desktop", you need to add your username after the Users folder. For example:

```
File file = new File("/Users/LuxuryMode/Desktop/sample.json");
```

Comment: its not working with android I'm getting file not found

Comment: @coder: I'm not sure why you were expecting my answer to work with Android - this is a Mac question, not an Android question.

Comment: Never mind, I'm working with android on eclipse editor on mac and since ur using java so I thought it would work, anyway solved my problem by putting the file in the assets.

Comment: This is half true. By default, macOS hard disks are formatted case-preserving but case-insensitive. So while making the case of the path match the case on disk is good style, it has nothing to do with whether this code will work. (Though you *can* choose to format hard disks as case sensitive, this is an option, not how a Mac hard disk comes from the factory). Adding the missing user name Is more likely the actual fix.

Comment: @uliwitness yeah, you're right. The first paragraph is probably better suited as a footnote. But I'll remove it and upvote your comment instead.

Answer (score 4):

To get to know your correct path to be given, drag n drop your file in `Mac terminal`, which would give you the path of the file which would look like 
`ex:/Users/Smith/Desktop/PI/ABApBASICS.docx`

All you got to do is paste this code in Eclipse but mind you blackslash would throw you an error: `invalid escape sequence`
solution:
`ex://Users//Harish//Desktop//PI//ABApBASICS.docx`
I was able to read the file without error inputting above path.

Comment: This is not a valid Mac path, and this answer is inconsistent. Mac paths do not start with volume letters like "ex:", that is a Windows thing. Also, these are slashes, not backslashes, which should not need escaping. (Again, Windows uses backslashes). Dragging a file on the Mac Terminal will produce a standard Unix path. However, it will use backslashes to escape spaces, which is not valid in Java strings, so _that_ is where you should watch your backslashes.