# How to pass a file path in Eclipse Run Configuration on a mac machine?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to use Eclipse argument (the one from the run configuration menu) to pass a file path to my java application, but I'm using a mac machine.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
        // Read the filename from the command line argument
        String filename = args[0];
        BufferedReader inputStream = null;

        String fileLine;
        try 
        {
            inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
 }
```

I assume it should be somewhere here,

[image]

[image]

but whatever I enter, it gives me an error of NOT SUCH A DIRECTORY.

Any recommendations?

Thank you

Comment: Try it by giving full path, as in, D:\\<parentFolderName>\<childFolder>\fileName.<extension>

Comment: @404BrainNotFound, So the thing is we don't have D:\\ in a mac machine. The path is probably something like:  /Users/../Documents/... but I don't know how the format needs to be for eclipse environment argument.

Comment: the format stays the same, when i mentioned  `D:\\<parentFolderName>\<childFolder>\fileName.<extension>` it was for windows, you just need to figure out where you have stored your file and provide that path instead.

Comment: Duplicate to [path-to-file-on-a-mac-filenotfoundexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972026/path-to-file-on-a-mac-filenotfoundexception)

Comment: If the path contains whitespace, surround it with quotes: `"/Users/../Documents/../testFile.txt"`. A relative path is resolved to the _Working directory_ (also in the same dialog), in your case the project folder (not the source folder).